# How can i get the post's full html source by its ID?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, html, curl

Is there a way that i can get the HTML source of a single post dynamically from within WordPress site?

for example, if i wanted an external html I would use:

```
file_get_contents($url)
```

or using cUrl, But I'm looking for a way to do it from within my WordPress to get full qualified HTML for one of my posts

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Can you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: Including header, footer, and sidebar etc? Or just the post content?

Comment: @Jacob yes including header, footer..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the post's ID, I assume that you are the owner of the blog ( Not because others can't have the ID, but because only the owner should do such tasks ).

To convert the post ID to the post's URL, you can use `get_the_permalink()`:

```
$url = get_the_permalink( $id );
```

Afterward, you can use `file_get_contents()` to fetch its content, including the full source of that web page. So, your full code will be:

```
$url = get_the_permalink( $id );
$data = file_get_contents( $url );
```

Which data is your HTML source. Note that this will only work in the WordPress environment.

Comment: Thanks @Jack , indeed i want it to work from within WordPress environment, are there any solutions using WordPress internal functions/hooks to do the same ?

Comment: Hi. Those are internal WordPress functions though.